# Link formatter to display link title, image and summary

Tags: meta-tags

I know I've seen a module that does this at some point in the past but can't seem to find it right now. In Drupal 8, I have a link field. I want to fetch that link's metadata so I can display the link's title / summary / image via a formatter (think of how facebook displays links). I don't remember if this worked server-side, storing the info in the drupal db or client-side via javascript (and for the prototype I'm putting together, I doesn't matter).

I'd appreciate any help before I decide to go and write it myself.

Comment: Here's a great answer to acheive what you want, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711554/7576961. You can maybe create a custom field formatter that implements that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) and Tokens, also check out [Field Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter) if you need to wrap the link around an image field.

For most control create one yourself, there are different tutorials for that, start here: [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0)

Comment: Of course but the heavy lifting is fetching the page and extracting the title, summary and image url from the metadata.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood when you said link metadata, I thought you were talking about the link field content, but now it seems you mean the whole page metadata. Are you using the module https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag? Are you trying to create something like social media card for your content?